# Get data array from object in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, kriging

I'm using a [library](http://pykriging.com/) which produces 3 plots given an object `k`.

I need to figure the data points `(x,y,z)` that produced these plot, but the problem is that the plots comes from a function from `k`.

The library I'm using is `pyKriging` and [this](https://github.com/capaulson/pyKriging) is their github repository.

A simplified version of their example [code](https://github.com/capaulson/pyKriging/blob/master/examples/2D_simple_train.py) is:

```
import pyKriging  
from pyKriging.krige import kriging  
from pyKriging.samplingplan import samplingplan

sp = samplingplan(2)  
X = sp.optimallhc(20)

testfun = pyKriging.testfunctions().branin  
y = testfun(X)

k = kriging(X, y, testfunction=testfun, name='simple')   
k.train()
k.plot()
```

The full code, comments and output can be found [here](http://pykriging.com/).

In summary, I'm trying to get the `numpy` array that produced these plots so I can create plots that follows my formatting styles.

I'm not knowledgeable about going into library codes in Python and I appreciate any help!

Comment: What are your formatting styles? You may just set them first and then call `k.plot()`.

Comment: Are you expecting us to search the `kringing` docs and/or code to find this?  The answer lies with their code.  It's not a general `numpy` question.  In `pandas` you uses a `.values` method to extract an array from a dataframe.

Comment: You may want to ask this question directly on `github` or `pyKriging` site. This is a complex code and as @hpaulj  pointed, nobody is going to go through the code and provide you with an answer.

Comment: This is a valid question about programming using an open source tool, so it can be answered, once enough information are given in the question about what kind of plotting styles are meant. Since kriging uses numpy arrays and methods in its code, the numpy tag is valid. So, again @yellow01, you should provide detail about what you want to style.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. At first I was wondering if I could somehow have acess to the `numpy` array that produced the plots without having to go through the library. As @hpaulj stated, something like `.values` in `pandas`. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the style is simply the first and second plot without the contour filling (`contour()` instead of `contourf()`). Do you believe the only way to achieve this is to tweak the original library or I can place a new line in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single data array that produces the plot. Instead many arrays used for plotting are generated inside the kriging plot function.
Changing the filled contours to line contours is of course not a style option. One therefore needs to use the code from the original plotting function.

An option is to subclass `kriging` and implement a custom plot function (let's call it `myplot`). In this function, one can use `contour` instead of `contourf`. Naturally, it's also possible to change it completely to one's needs.

```
import pyKriging  
from pyKriging.krige import kriging  
from pyKriging.samplingplan import samplingplan
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyKriging(kriging):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        kriging.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
    def myplot(self,labels=False, show=True, **kwargs):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
        # Create a set of data to plot
        plotgrid = 61
        x = np.linspace(self.normRange[0][0], self.normRange[0][1], num=plotgrid)
        y = np.linspace(self.normRange[1][0], self.normRange[1][1], num=plotgrid)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
        # Predict based on the optimized results
        zs = np.array([self.predict([xi,yi]) for xi,yi in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
        Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)
        #Calculate errors
        zse = np.array([self.predict_var([xi,yi]) for xi,yi in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
        Ze = zse.reshape(X.shape)

        spx = (self.X[:,0] * (self.normRange[0][1] - self.normRange[0][0])) + self.normRange[0][0]
        spy = (self.X[:,1] * (self.normRange[1][1] - self.normRange[1][0])) + self.normRange[1][0]

        contour_levels = kwargs.get("levels", 25)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(222)
        CS = plt.contour(X,Y,Ze, contour_levels)
        plt.colorbar()
        plt.plot(spx, spy,'or')

        ax = fig.add_subplot(221)
        if self.testfunction:
            # Setup the truth function
            zt = self.testfunction( np.array(zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))) )
            ZT = zt.reshape(X.shape)
            CS = plt.contour(X,Y,ZT,contour_levels ,colors='k',zorder=2, alpha=0)

        if self.testfunction:
            contour_levels = CS.levels
            delta = np.abs(contour_levels[0]-contour_levels[1])
            contour_levels = np.insert(contour_levels, 0, contour_levels[0]-delta)
            contour_levels = np.append(contour_levels, contour_levels[-1]+delta)

        CS = plt.contour(X,Y,Z,contour_levels,zorder=1)
        plt.plot(spx, spy,'or', zorder=3)
        plt.colorbar()

        ax = fig.add_subplot(212, projection='3d')
        ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=3, cstride=3, alpha=0.4)
        if self.testfunction:
            ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, ZT, rstride=3, cstride=3)
        if show:
            plt.show()



sp = samplingplan(2)  
X = sp.optimallhc(20)

testfun = pyKriging.testfunctions().branin  
y = testfun(X)

k = MyKriging(X, y, testfunction=testfun, name='simple')   
k.train()
k.myplot()
```

[image]

Comment: This is certainly the answer for the question @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. In order to get the data array that produced these plots I added `return X,Y,Z`. Now, say I just want these data arrays (`X,Y,Z`) for further use and I don't mind about plotting it. Is there another way using a subclass to just `return` the `X`, `Y`, `Z`, etc arrays? If so this would definitely be a more general answer to this question and title. Thanks!

Comment: The arrays that are used for plotting are `X`, `Y`, `Z`,`ZT` and  `Ze`. Thery are generated within the plotting method. If you only need those you can delete everything related to plotting from the custom plot function and return only those arrays.